# What's the right way to use historyserver of hadoop 2.2?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am using the hadoop hadoop-2.2.0. I can start historyserver in the master node and slave node?

1. But I am not sure do i need start the history server on the slave
   node?
2. If I start one history server on master, can i get all the logs of all jobs?
3. If I need start all the servers in both master and slave node, is there any command to start all using one command? Not start each server one by one.

Any comments are welcome.

Comment: YARN has single Mapreduce job history server on master node. As indicated by the name, the function of the mapreduce job history server is to store and serve a history of the mapreduce jobs that were run on the cluster.

Comment: How to retrieve this history, means there may be a file(or whatever ) storing all history of jobs. How can i see this history?

Comment: Also it's nice to use log aggregation if you intend to use historyserver. It makes thing much more easy and simple.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need only one historyserver. It can run on any node you like, including a dedicated node of its own, but traditionally runs on the same node as the resourcemanager. The one history server is declared in [mapred-site.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html#Configuring_the_Hadoop_Daemons_in_Non-Secure_Mode):

- `mapreduce.jobhistory.address`: MapReduce JobHistory Server host:port Default port is 10020.
- `mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address`: MapReduce JobHistory Server Web UI host:port   Default port is 19888.
- `mapreduce.jobhistory.intermediate-done-dir`: Directory where history files are written by MapReduce jobs (in HDFS). Default is `/mr-history/tmp`
- `mapreduce.jobhistory.done-dir`: Directory where history files are managed by the MR JobHistory Server (in HDFS). Default is `/mr-history/done`

You can access the history via the [historyserver REST API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/HistoryServerRest.html), you do not access directly the internal history files. For casual browsing, the history is available in the resouremanager web UI.

Comment: Suppose I want to ship all the logs to an ELK stack for statistical querying, why not access the history files directly?